# Is it possible to create an IPS rule to Checkpoint 5200 PB-20 Firewall for Mysql packets

Tags: firewall, checkpoint

Is it possible to create an IPS rule to Checkpoint 5200 PB-20 Firewall that assesses the content from incoming packets for Mysql database server (port 3306)? If the packet is according to real Mysql packet then this can be forwarded to the database server. Otherwise, it will be dropped. The idea is to avoid DDOS atacks by sending massive TCP connections to Mysql server by Telnet or another application.

Comment: It takes a NextGen firewall to look inside the packets the way you want. Traditional firewalls do not do that. We have no idea bout the model. Please edit the question to include that.

Comment: What should I change about the question? I don't understand very well the last sentence.

Comment: There are various models of that brand of firewall. Which model do you mean? different models have different features and capabilities.

Comment: Ok. This is a FW Checkpoint 5200 PB-20. I'm going to edit it

Comment: That model appears to support IPS features which should already do exactly what you want. It will help block or reject recognized attacks using common network threats or exploits. Simply enable the IPS capabilities of the firewall to inspect traffic passing through the firewall and it will help protect your servers that are on the inside networks.

Comment: @user3637971 Usually, mysql calls come from the application server, so you might want to restrict the IP source addresses to exactly that (and perhaps some dev machines).

Comment: Keep in mind that creating an IPS rule to drop illegitimate Mysql packets does not lead to avoiding DDoS attacks. In fact, on a Mysql server, it is more effective to DDoS it by sending legitimate requests than illegitimate requests. This is because legitimate requests make the server do work, while illegitimate requests are discarded fairly easily. Your best action is to permit only particular source IP addresses to reach the Mysql server. And then use IPS rules to make sure if any unauthorized malware gets on a legitimate server, it can't attempt any attacks using malformed packets.

Comment: I can consider permitting specific IPs which is a good option. Although, I don't think that it's more effective to DDOS by sending legitimate. I see it as relative.